# Custom Validation Not Executing

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, data-annotations

I have a View Model class in a WPF application that has some very complex validation. I have implemented the `IValidatableObject` interface to provide the custom validation logic. The problem is that my `IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)` is never called!

Here is the code attempting the validation:
`Validator.TryValidateObject(RMA, new ValidationContext(RMA, null, null), result);`

Any ideas why the `Validator` object is not calling my custom validation code?

Comment: Breakpoint may help you? Can you give us examples of your code or a snippet representing your problem?

Comment: A breakpoint is set but is never hit. Honestly my `Validate` method is empty at this point.

Comment: Sorry to repeat but; Can you give us examples of your code or a snippet representing your problem?

Comment: The code is pretty uninteresting:
`public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{ string s = "breakpoint here"; }`

`Validator.TryValidateObject(RMA, new ValidationContext(RMA, null, null), result);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was that I was I had `[Required]` on one of the fields in the custom class and the `Validator` will not perform custom validation until all data annotation validation has been completed.  Removing the `[Required]` allows the custom validation to execute.

`EDIT:`

When validating an object, the following process is applied in Validator.ValidateObject:

1. Validate property-level attributes
2. *If any validators are invalid, abort validation returning the failure(s)*
3. Validate the object-level attributes
4. *If any validators are invalid, abort validation returning the failure(s)*
5. If on the desktop framework and the object implements `IValidatableObject`, then call its Validate method and return any failure(s)

http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2009/10/16/validator.aspx

Validation will abort at step #2.

Comment: How did you get to that in the end? =)

Comment: I started to use custom ValidationAttribute classes because of the issue.